# Azure pipelines secret variable and react app deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have been trying for a few days on how to use an environment secret variable set in azure pipelines.

Here is source code where I get the environment variable value.

[image]

Here is the .env file I used with the value

[image]

Below is the TEST word successfully shown when I try to run in vscode via yarn start.
[image]

I setup environment variable and set variable as secret in the azure pipeline.
I followed some microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) as well as some other answers here in stackoverflow.

[image]

I setup powershell task in azure pipelines to get secret variable.
[image]

All task run successfully. All task for IIS Deployment also run successfully.

[image]

But when I open the web app in the II Server, the result is TEST is not displayed at all.

## Heading

[image]

If I use the pipeline variable as plaintext instead of secret, TEST is *successfully displayed*.
Did someone encountered this before and solved it?

Comment: in which task, do you use the secret? In the powershell task? Why do you want to display your secret? What is your powershell code?

Comment: @MoonHorse, I use the secret in the powershell task. The script of the powershell task is displayed on the right side on the picture above. I just logged in the first few samples for calling the display. Then on the bottom of the task on the variable area, I set the environment variable using the secret.